# How to verify that one of the api calls has been made in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, web-api-testing, cypress-intercept

I think the answer must be pretty simple but i can't find it...

How to verify that one of the calls has been made?

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/api/v1/url1').as('call1');

cy.intercept('PUT', '/api/v1/url2').as('call2');



cy.get('[data-cy-name="submit"]').click();
```

Wait with an array verifies both calls has been made.

```
cy.wait(['@call1', '@call2']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wildcard both the `method` and the `url` of the request.

Here's an example test that you can use to explore the options.

It uses the `cy.intercept(routeMatcher, staticResponse)` pattern so that we can stub the call and mess about without 404'ing.

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: '*',
  url: '**/api/v1/*',
}, 
{}                   // stubbing for this mini-test
).as('api')


// Fire the GET url1 example
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('domain/api/v1/url1:abc', {method:'GET'})
})

cy.wait('@api').its('request')
  .should(req => {
    expect(req.method).to.eq('GET')
    expect(req.url).to.contain('/url1')
  })


// Fire the PUT url2 example
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('domain/api/v1/url2:def', {method:'PUT'})
})

cy.wait('@api').its('request')
.should(req => {
  expect(req.method).to.eq('PUT')
  expect(req.url).to.contain('/url2')
})
```

If you want to be specific about only catching `GET` and `PUT`, you can use regex

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: /GET|PUT/,
  url: '**/api/v1/*',
}, 
{}
).as('api')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make sure that at least one of your intercepts is matched, and not specifically `call1` or `call2`, you can [alias individual requests](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests) to give them a "shared" alias.

```js
cy.intercept('/api/v1/*', (req) => {
  // only alias the request if it includes one of our specified endpoints
  if (req.url.includes('url1') || req.url.includes('url2')) {
    req.alias = 'foo';
  }
})
cy.get('[data-cy-name="submit"]').click();
cy.wait('@foo');
```